# Starting iptables stops communication between two virtual machines connected by a bridge

Tags: centos, networking, iptables, firewall, bridge

I created a bridge named eth2 with the interface gre1 between 2 virtual machines VM1 and VM2.

The following is VM1 with bridge device eth2.

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
eth2            8000.162f8564eb74       no              gre1
```

The interface IP of VM1 is 172.80.1.1 and the interface IP of VM2 is 172.80.1.2
When iptables is stopped in VM1, I am able to ping the interface IP of VM2 from VM1. On starting iptables though, the ping will not work.

```
# ping 172.80.1.2
PING 172.80.1.2 (172.80.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 172.80.1.2 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5240ms
```

Here is what my iptables looks like.

```
    # iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
72854   10M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 10defaults */
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 10defaults */
   75  5428 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* 10defaults */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 /* 20ssh */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 /* 30https */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 /* 30https */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 /* 50snmp-health */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 /* 50snmp-health */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:123 /* 60ntp */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5671 /* 70rabbitmq */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3999 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4000 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4001 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4002 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4003 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4004 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4005 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4006 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4007 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4008 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4009 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4010 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4011 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4012 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4013 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4014 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4015 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4016 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4017 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4018 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4019 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4020 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4021 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4022 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4023 /* 80debug */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:15672 /* 85rabbitmq-ui */
 1250  250K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 99finish */ reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:162 /* eth2_RULE */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9990 /* eth2_RULE */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9990 /* eth2_RULE */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 /* eth2_RULE */
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:443 state ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth2   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 72917 packets, 10M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Also, `sysctl -a | grep bridge-nf gives`

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged = 0
```

What could be causing this to not work? Is there something wrong with the iptable rules here?

Comment: if `gre1` is a GRE tunnel interface, you'll have to provide information on its endpoints: iptables might block them, thus rendering the interface inoperative.

Comment: Yes, gre1 was a GRE tunnel interface. Providing endpoint information for it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the policy to accepted for my gre tunnel interface gre1.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
```

This helped me to get it working.